# In transaction, pulling from array field in Same collection, mongoDB write conflict problem

Tags: mongodb

First of all, sorry for bad English.

We currently use MongoDB v4.0.22 (enterprise, atlas)

I don't know how I solve this write conflict.

Scenario is when deleting multiple collection using single remove Restful API.

```
many users call deleteById RESTful API in very short time.
```

Each DeleteOneById Request scenario is

1. Find Delete target by id.
2. remove it.
3. push from parent. (pulling from array)

Problem is **3. Push from parent.** When remove 3 from source code, it works fine.

Important is,
***All request has same parent. so, main problem causes from pulling same collection's array field in each different transaction.***

I don't know how can I fix this, furthermore I don't know MongoDB can handle this.

Below is related error results.

```
MongoError: WriteConflict ... {
  operationTime: Timestamp { _bsontype: 'Timestamp', low_: 1, high_: 1613471664 },
  ok: 0,
  code: 112,
  codeName: 'WriteConflict',
  '$clusterTime': {
    clusterTime: Timestamp { _bsontype: 'Timestamp', low_: 1, high_: 1613471664 },
    signature: { hash: [Binary], keyId: [Long] }
  },
  [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set { 'TransientTransactionError' }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this error happens *occasionally*, use the documented withTransaction API which would retry the transaction automatically.

If this error happens *frequently*, change your schema and/or your operations to not frequently write the same document in concurrent transactions.

Comment: Oh, this error happens always when our frontend try to delete items at one time.
Is any fundamental solution that can keep these schema?
Thanks for your answer, anyway.

Comment: The error cannot always happen. The first deletion will not produce it.

Comment: yep, as you mentioned, I changed my schema.